# Pass value through the segue for programmatically-generated buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, segue

I have a ViewController and a set of buttons programmatically generated there. Each button have to perform segue with identifier and pass information through the segue, e.g. button's number.
How to add some kind of unique id to each button (which can be provided by CoreData) and pass this value through the segue? Here is my code for creating a button, it is being placed in for-loop.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:)

 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[self.containerView addSubview:button];
```

What code to add to button e.g. to set some iVar?

Comment: Give each button a unique tag and pass it in `prepareForSegue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't set the action for your button to be performSegue, use your own function instead

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonPressed:)];
```

the implmentation of my button can then do the segue.  How to know which button was pressed?  you could store references to each button and then compare them to the button object that gets passed into the method, or you could use the tag property:

```
button.tag = 1;
```

your button function could look something like this.  The sender parameter is for you to attach any type of data that you want the prepareForSegue function to recieve

```
- (void)myButonPressed:(UIButton *)button {
   if (button.tag == 1) {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"button1Segue" sender:@"any data you want to send"];
   }       
}
```

Then your prepareForSegue would look something like

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"button1Segue"]) {
        UIViewController *dest = segue.destinationViewController;
        dest.specialString = sender;
    }
}
```

Update:

The UIViewController doc has this to say about the sender parameter: "The object that you want to use to initiate the segue. This object is made available for informational purposes during the actual segue."  In other words the sender parameter is how you pass information (e.g. an object like a string, array, dictionary, custom object) to the prepareForSegue method.  So if buttonA needs to send a string, maybe it's title, to the destination viewController the sender parameter is how you pass it.

Comment: Brandon, thank you! What is this? : sender:@"any data you want to send"];


Am I correct, that @selector(myButtonPressed:) calls method in .m file, its like [self myButtonPressed:] ?

Comment: Yes your mostly correct about the myButtonPressed call, except that it passes the button as a parameter because you add the : when you specified the selector.  This is exactly the same behavior as if you were to ctrl click and drag an action from the storyboard to your .m file.  If you declared the method first then started typing the @selector part autocomplete will usually kick in and fill in the method name with the colon for you.